# Cryptopp: Decrypt array of char with binary data

Tags: c++, crypto++

I'm almost new in Cryptopp.

This is my encrypted data:

```
...
char* mDataBuffer = new char[length];
inFile.read((char*)(&mDataBuffer[0]), length);
```

By reading the inFile, now the mDataBuffer array contains encrypted binary data.
There's no problem with this mDataBuffer (tested carefully!).

Now I need to decrypt this array.
Note that the file (now presented as mDataBuffer array) is encrypted in java or .net in AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING.

The decrypted data should be in char type (or could be converted to it!)

Here's my c++ code for decryption:

```
byte mkey[] = "12345678"; // note that the key is only 8 chars
CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption decryptor;
decryptor.SetKeyWithIV(mkey, 16, mkey); // IV and key are same. I used 16 bytes and I think it causes Cryptopp to use PKCS#7 padding (Am I write?!)

char* decryptedBytes = new char[length];
```

Then I've tried many things, for example:

**Try 1:**

```
std::string plain;
StreamTransformationFilter stf(decryptor, new CryptoPP::StringSink(plain));
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    stf.Put(mDataBuffer[i], sizeof(mDataBuffer[i]));
}
stf.MessageEnd();
```

With this code I get this error message:
CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext at memory location

The mDataBuffer is binary data and contains 0x00 data (or '\0').

**Try 2:**

```
ArraySink cs((byte*)&decryptedBytes[0], length);
StreamTransformationFilter stf(decryptor, new Redirector(cs));
ArraySource((const char*)(&mDataBuffer[0]), true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(d, new Redirector(cs)));
```

With this code I get this error message:
CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext at memory location

Note: I cant use FileSource (maybe I'm wrong!). Because the file has extra data and this data is removed manually after it has been read to mDataBuffer (for simplicity I didn't include the code here)

I wonder how I stock to this!
Thanks any help or hint.

Comment: AES block size is 128 bits (16 bytes). The key (and iv for cbc-mode) are likewise the same width. Therefore your 'key' of `"12345678"`makes no sense. And it most-certainly makes no sense as both the key *and* the IV of a CBC entry state, but that's another matter. Are you *sure* your 'key' isn't really a *password* to a key-derivation function that *generates* the *real* AES-key used for this operation?

Comment: I think your right. for example in java I know this code generates the code: mkey.getBytes("UTF-16le"), "AES"), and in .net this one: byte[] mkey = UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes("12345678"). This generates mkey byte array in this way: { 49, 0, 50, 0, 51, 0, 52, 0, 53, 0, 54, 0, 55, 0, 56, 0 }. Encoding in UTF-16le each character uses 2 bytes witch the second byte is zero. But how could I get this kind of mkey in C++?

Comment: That's trivial, and incredibly disappointing if that is how they 'generate' their key, considering half the octets are known-zero. You could easily manufacture a 16-octet 'key' from that string a number of ways, including a vector with every odd slot set to zero. That 'key' is several things; secure isn't one of them.  A proper key-derivation from string is supposed to be *expensive* to brute force, so much so you're no better off than just trying to brute force the actual key.  Google PBKDF2 and bcrypt for far more secure methods of generating password-hash-based key derivation.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I'll promise to use and create proper key. But is there any solution for my current problem? Suppose that the key and iv are changed properly. How could I decrypt binary char array?

Comment: By doing exactly what you said: Changing the key and IV properly. Make both (I'd use vectors just to make it easier. (but then again, I'd use OpenSSL::libcrypto for this myself; I don't generally touch CryptoPP ).